# how do I arrange time for a schedule on vba

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I am working on this schedule in Excel that will let me know if am scheduling only one person at a specific shift. So what the macro does it goes over a specific list that I have attached and checks their starting time and ending time. I want the macro to let me know if I schedule someone at a specific time that if there will be overlapping someone else. The following code is working, but now that I am testing to see if it works I put a name, app server they will be running, starting time and ending time. So the macro goes over a loop to check the table that I provide on excel, but I'm getting an error on the time. For example if I put the starting time at 6:00 am and the ending time at 6:30 am and on the table provided I have someone else running that app at  rows tart time at 5:59 am to rowendtime= 6:35 am it should show me a "conflict" because they are overlapping but for some reason it is showing "no conflict" Any help would be really appreciated. Here is the code:

```
Public Sub LoopRows(Appserver As String, StartTime As Date, EndTime As Date)

  Dim x As Integer
  Dim NumROws As Integer
  NumROws = Range("Sheet3!C5").End(xlDown).Row - Range("Sheet3!C5").Row
  Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
  Range("Sheet3!C5").Select
  msgbox Appserver
  msgbox StartTime
  msgbox EndTime
  For x = 1 To NumROws
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    If (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Appserver) Then
         Dim RowStartTime As Date
         Dim RowEndTime As Date
         msgbox ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
         msgbox RowStartTime = Val(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value)
         msgbox RowEndTime = Val(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value)
         If (((EndTime > RowStartTime) And (EndTime < RowEndTime)) Or (((StartTime > RowStartTime) And (StartTime < RowEndTime))) Or (((StartTime < RowStartTime) And (EndTime > RowEndTime)))) Then
            msgbox "Conflict"
         Else
            msgbox "noConflict"
         End If
     End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the edits @comintern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify your `If` condition.  It's impossible for two time spans to overlap without one starting time falling between the other span's start and end:

Partial overlap case:

```
Start1                        End1
  |----------------------------|
              Start2                 End2
                |---------------------|
```

Complete overlap case:

```
Start1                        End1
  |----------------------------|
      Start2            End2
        |----------------|
```

You can make the `If` condition this:

```
If (StartTime > RowStartTime) And (StartTime < RowEndTime) Or _
   (RowStartTime > StartTime) And (RowStartTime < EndTime) Then
```

**Edit:**  It should look more like the code below.  Note that I'm assuming from the original code that the "Appserver" value is in column "F", starting times are in column "H", and ending times are in column "I". There is also no error checking on the `CDate` calls (but then again there wasn't on the `Val` calls either).

```
Public Sub LoopRows(Appserver As String, StartTime As Date, EndTime As Date)
    Dim CurrentRow As Integer, LastRow As Integer
    Dim RowStartTime As Date, RowEndTime As Date
    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
        LastRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For CurrentRow = 6 To LastRow
            If (.Cells(CurrentRow, 6).Value = Appserver) Then
                RowStartTime = CDate(.Cells(CurrentRow, 8).Value)
                RowEndTime = CDate(.Cells(CurrentRow, 9).Value)
                If (StartTime > RowStartTime) And (StartTime < RowEndTime) Or _
                   (RowStartTime > StartTime) And (RowStartTime < EndTime) Then
                    MsgBox "Conflict"
                Else
                    MsgBox "noConflict"
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the response. I switched my code to yours and I did the same problem and I did not work. I input the time for 4:00 to 4:15 and the saved time on the Excel sheet was 4:00 to 4:05 and it gave me no conflict. Do you think this would be because I dont have a statement in the code where it says they can not equal each other? @comintern

Comment: I'm assuming that you took the `MsgBox` calls out of your assignments?

Comment: I just took them off and now I received an error on this line of code: ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value it says that value is an invalid used of property. @Comintern

Comment: @GuillermoPereira - That isn't an assignment. I was referring to the lines `msgbox RowStartTime = Val(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value)` and `msgbox RowEndTime = Val(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value)`, which I'm assuming you put in for debugging.