# Macro Works on Old Worksheet, New Worksheet Loops Endlessly

Tags: excel, vba

Working with a code to remove all punctuation and odd characters. I tried adding a section where it would add a space to the beginning and end of cell to ensure a later search works. It endlessly looped, so I took that new code out, however it still loops endlessly.

I tried closing and reopening the file and it still endlessly loops. An old copy works just fine. Why is this? (I'm not sure how to attach the files. Any help with that would be wonderful as well.)

The old code and this code are identical (I copy pasted, and retyped it manually, several times to make sure).

I've added another functionality, but it's a simple cell counter in a different Macro. I can't see why that would affect this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemovePunctuation()
Dim cell As Range
With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
  .Pattern = "[^A-Za-z\ ]"
  .Global = True
  For Each cell In Worksheets("Raw").Range("A2:A1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    cell.Value = .Replace(cell.Value, vbNullString)
  Next cell
End With

For Each cell In Worksheets("Raw").Range("A2:A1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
cell.Value = LCase(cell.Value)
Next cell

End Sub
```

Other Codes on the Same Worksheet -- counts unique words

```
Sub ExtractWords()
Dim X As Variant, S As Variant, S2 As Variant, S3 As Variant, str As Variant, key As Variant
Dim oDict As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim i As Double, j As Double, k As Double
Dim Anchor As Range

Set oDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

With ThisWorkbook
   'Clear past output
   With .Sheets("Output")
       .Range("a2:" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Address).ClearContents
   End With

'Fill array with text to search
   With .Sheets("Raw")
       X = .Range("a2:a" & .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
   End With
End With

For i = LBound(X) To UBound(X)
 S = Split(X(i, 1), " ")

  For j = LBound(S, 1) To UBound(S, 1)
      If oDict.Exists(LCase(S(j))) Then
          oDict.Item(LCase(S(j))) = oDict.Item(LCase(S(j))) + 1
      Else
          oDict.Add LCase(S(j)), 1
      End If
  Next j
Next i

'Output results to sheet "Output"
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
For Each key In oDict.Keys
    Set Anchor = .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Anchor = key
    Anchor.Offset(0, 1) = oDict.Item(key)
Next key

.Range("a1:" & .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Address).Sort .Range("b:b"), xlDescending

End With

End Sub
```

Adds a column that calculates how many sentences use that word. (Why I need to add a space at the beginning and end of each sentence.)

```
Option Explicit
Sub CountCards()

Worksheets("Output").Activate
'Range("C2:C5000").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(Raw!A:A,""* ""&A2&"" *"")=0,"""",COUNTIF(Raw!A:A,""* ""&A2&"" *""))"

Range("C2:C5000").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(Raw!A:A,""* ""&A2&"" *"")=0,"""",COUNTIF(Raw!A:A,""* ""&A2&"" *""))"

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried it on a smaller range (e.g., `Range("A2:A10")` and step thru the code manually using F8 to ensure that it's actually looping infinitely? It's possible that it's just taking you longer than you think it should -- you're doubling the loop which is unnecessary to begin with, just do the `cell.Value = lCase(.Replace(cell.Value, vbNullString))` inside the first loop, and omit the second loop completely.

Comment: That make sense, but on an identical worksheet (older version) the code runs in about 2 seconds.

Comment: Does the infinite worksheet contain any event handlers like `Worksheet_Change` which would possibly trigger an infinite loop unless you take precuation to `Application.EnableEvents = False` (and reset to `True` at the end of procedure)?

Comment: You're using an iterator on a `Range` and have the possibility of changing the `Range` inside the loop.  If a cell doesn't contain *any* of the allowed characters, you'll set it to `vbNullString` and remove it from `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)`.  I'd recommend switching to a standard `For` loop.

Comment: Even with the double-loop, this runs for me in less than 1 second (Excel Timer function displays 0). My data is not enormous, but does contain 1000 cells and some of them are null/empty cells. There may also be an issue with `Calculation` occurring during the loop if any of these cells are dependents in functions elsewhere.

Comment: @David Zemens: You're right. It is just taking a long time, but in an old version that exact code ran very quickly. Now it's taking about 2 seconds per cell as opposed to 2 seconds total. I tried removing the second loop and it did not speed up. The cells are straight text. No calculations.

Comment: @Comintern : Could you give me an example of this? I am very new to VBA.

Comment: A bit long to post as a comment - [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38690660/4088852) shows looping by rows though. The bit starting at `LastRow = `...  Just ignore what's in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion is that it's related to *Calculation*. You have a procedure inserting formula in column C on another sheet, which references column A. If Column C has already been populated with the formulae, then changing the values (dependents) in column A may be triggering re-calculation of all of those formulas.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemovePunctuation()
Dim cell As Range
Dim calc as Long
'## Get the original calculation state:
calc = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
  .Pattern = "[^A-Za-z\ ]"
  .Global = True
  For Each cell In Worksheets("Raw").Range("A2:A1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    cell.Value = .Replace(cell.Value, vbNullString)
  Next cell
End With

For Each cell In Worksheets("Raw").Range("A2:A1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
cell.Value = LCase(cell.Value)
Next cell
'## Reset the calculation to original state
Application.Calculation = calc
End Sub
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: When I put a simple `CountIf` formula in another column, runtime went up from <1 second to about 15-20 seconds. :)

Comment: The bonus is that I would have run into this multiple times in the future and can now fix it. :)